# Xcode/iPad animateWithDuration background/foreground

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a looped animation in a UIViewController which is called in the viewDidAppear function:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{ 
                     _introImage.center = CGPointMake(INTRO_IMAGE_X_END, INTRO_IMAGE_Y);

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     _introImage.center = CGPointMake(INTRO_IMAGE_X_START, INTRO_IMAGE_Y);
                 }];
```

When I put the app into the background and bring it back to the foreground the animation stops. Why is this and what could I do to restart the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in it's own method and call that method from viewDidAppear, and also in applicationDidBecomeActive, which is in your AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)animate {
[UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{ 
                     _introImage.center = CGPointMake(INTRO_IMAGE_X_END, INTRO_IMAGE_Y);

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     _introImage.center = CGPointMake(INTRO_IMAGE_X_START, INTRO_IMAGE_Y);
                 }];

}
```

In order to fire the method from "viewDidAppear" call the method with a single line , like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self animate];
}
```

And to fire the animation from the app delegate when the app becomes active:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewcontroller animate];
}
```

This is all assuming you might want to use viewDidAppear for other things as well. Separating the animation into it's own method lets you call it exclusively, instead of running everything inside of viewDidAppear.

Comment: That's a neat solution. Thanks. I would still like to get an idea of why the animation stops (I'm assuming that it should not) as I am having other problems when putting the app into background/foreground.

Comment: Have you tried it in viewDidLoad? I uses some similar code like this and it worked fine in viewDidLoad even when the app goes inactive, then back.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't clear the problem. As I mentioned above I am having other problems so I wonder if I haven't accidentally set something up incorrectly.

Comment: I'd like to try and help if you wanted to share how you setup your app?

Comment: That's very kind. What do you need to know?

Comment: First, what are the "other" problems you're having, and second, is your view controller the Main view controller? is it a view that is visible when the app loads, or do you have to navigate to it?

Comment: Thanks for all your help @jhilgert00.

Your solution to the animation problem is correct. The animation stops when the view is not visible in any situation.

My other problems were resolved by changing a call to my setup function to use performSelectorInBackground rather than performSelector.